# QGIS processing toolbox: fieldcalculator - update only selected features is not possible

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I am working on a model where I need some calculations on only some selected features.

In the normal fieldcalculator you can check 'only update ... selected features'. When using the fieldcalculator from the processing toolbox, it is not possible to do that.

Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If you select your features before running the **Field Calculator** in the modeler, the output will contain only those selected features.

A workaround would be to use a **custom script** in your model which allows you to update your selected features **within the same layer**.

To do this, go to *Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script* and copy the following:

```
##Update selection=name
##Layer=vector
##Fields=Field Layer
##Formula=string

from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Fields)
e = QgsExpression(Formula)
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature( f )

layer.commitChanges()
```

Save the script into `C:\Users\You\.qgis2\processing\scripts`. In your modeler, create 3 parameters:

- Layer - *Vector layer*
- Field - *Table field*
- Formula - *String*

Then add the custom script from the list of algorithms and fill in the options:

[image: Update selection]

---

I ran a test on a layer where I want to change the values in the `id` field for the selected features:

[image: Attributes]

I ran the model selecting the layer, field and entering a value of `100`:

[image: Running model]

Once finished, the attributes of the layer should be updated:

[image: Attributes result]

*Note that you could use the same expressions as you would in the Field Calculator such as `CASE` statements etc. due to the [QgsExpression class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpression.html) used in the script.*

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with python but I trie it out.

Comment: @PieterB - Most welcome buddy! Hope it works for you :)